# The application ship(process com.example.ship) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: java, android, html

I am new for the android apps developing, I have created an sample app with a html design included with it.

when i was trying to install the app it displays
"The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again" in the device.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

```
MainActivity.java:

package com.example.ship;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.phonegap.*;



  public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      super.init();
      super.loadUrl("ship/assets/www/ship/task.html");

 }


 }
```

Comment: Post logcat error and also layout xml file.

Comment: Do you want to load your HTML file from `assets`?

Comment: Yes Apoorv.. my html file is named with task.html..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/ship/task.html");
```

Comment: sorry! I m very new to android and i don't even used logcat before.. can you please tutor me how to use and get error details from logcat..